# Error in using slice assignment in strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, slice

```
website = 'http://www.python.org'
website[18:] = 'com'
```

The error says:

> 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Why is this code snippet not legal?

Answer (score 8):

Because strings are immutable. Do it like this:

```
>>> website = 'http://www.python.org'
>>> website = website[:18] + 'com' # build a new string, reassign variable website
>>> website
'http://www.python.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to count how many characters to stop before you reach `.org`

you can use

```
website=website[:len(website)-4]+".com"
```